# How to detect if variable template specialization exists using concept?

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

I want to check is if I can safely use `MyTrait_v<T>` (not `MyTrait<T>::value`) using the concept `HasMyTrait_v<T>`. Here is my code, of course, it doesn't work.

```
#include<concepts>
#include<iostream>

template<typename T>
struct MyTrait;

template<typename T>
constexpr bool MyTrait_v = MyTrait<T>::value;

template<>
struct MyTrait<int> : std::true_type {};

template<>
constexpr bool MyTrait_v<double> = true;

template<typename T>
concept HasMyTrait_v = requires{
  MyTrait_v<T>;
};

int main()
{
  std::cout << "MyTrait_v<int>: " << MyTrait_v<int> << std::endl;
  std::cout << "MyTrait_v<double>: " << MyTrait_v<double> << std::endl;
  std::cout << "HasMyTrait_v<int>: " << HasMyTrait_v<int> << std::endl;

  // error C2027: use of undefined type 'MyTrait<float>'
  std::cout << "HasMyTrait_v<float>: " << HasMyTrait_v<float> << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: "*not `MyTrait<T>::value`*" But that *is* what you want to check for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With gcc only, you might make `MyTrait_v<T> = MyTrait<T>::value` SFINAE friendly:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr bool MyTrait_v;

template<typename T>
requires(requires{MyTrait<T>::value;})
constexpr bool MyTrait_v<T> = MyTrait<T>::value;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/eqcxqoKT9)

clang/msvc requires initialization though :/

We might trick clang with:

```
template<typename T>
struct NotDefined;

template<typename T>
constexpr bool MyTrait_v = NotDefined<T>::value;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vj3YsjEEW)

Unfortunately, I don't know workaround for your target msvc :-/

But anyway, the concept seems not return expected value (`true` for all cases).